# Testing if something is on screen with react

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, enzyme

I have an input field with a submit button and when someone enters something that text appears on the screen. how can I test that in react?

I know how to simulate the button click but what would the expectation be? or how would I actually be able to tell if the text is there?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `refs` to check the values of input fields using React. The `refs` provide the hooking interface between virtual DOM element of input fields to access it values.

Answer (score 0):

You scry for that input element by id or type or class. And you can access the text of that element by looking at `.value`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question... the first part of your question makes me think you want to detect when a user is typing some text in an input field, but the second part makes me think you want to automate a test, placing some text in the input and simulating click on a button, kinda confusing ...

In my last project I used that package instead of a classic input: [react-contenteditable](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable)

You can hook your code to events that this component is firing:

```
render() {

const { selectedDbItem } = this.props

return (
    <div>
        <ContentEditable
          onBlur={(e)=>this.onBlurField(e, 'supplier')}
          className="field-value"
          html={selectedDbItem ? selectedDbItem.supplier : ''}
          disabled={false}
          onChange={(e)=>this.onChangeField(e, 'supplier')}
          onKeyDown={(e) => this.onKeyDown(e)}
        />
      </div>
```

You can then implement the callbacks onBlur, onChange, onKeyDown (for input filtering for example ...) in the containing component.

Hope that helps